# C++ Error: no match for call to ‘(std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}) (unsigned int, char)

Tags: c++, string, c++11

When I want to use `string::s(unsigned, char)` to assigned `s`, the g++ output this error message.

There is my class:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

class Screen()
{
private:
    unsigned height = 0, width = 0;
    string contents;
public:
    Screen(unsigned ht, unsigned wd): height(ht), width(wd) {contents(ht * wd, ‘ ’）；}
}
```

Why it is wrong?

I know that it should be `Screen(unsigned ht, unsigned wd): height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht * wd, ‘ ’）{ }`, but why I can't use the function`string(unsigned, char)` to assigned a value for a string constructed?

Comment: You misspelled the syntax of the constructor initializer list.

Comment: Becuase you call `contents(ht * wd, ‘ ’)` in the body of your constructor, you're actually calling `std::string::operator()(unsigned, char)`, which `std::string` does not have. You should call it as part of the initializer list instead -- the same like `height` and `width`. Other than that, `‘ ’` is not valid C++, you need `' '`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to call `operator()(unsigned, char)` on a `std::string`, but `std::string` has no overloaded function call operators.

If you want to assign to it, you need to use an assignment, such as `contents = std::string(ht * wd, ' ');`

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like:

```
std::string contents;
int n = 10;
contents(10, '');
```

When you do this, std::string's constructor is not called, and there is no operator() in std::string.